Python logging: check if a log will print before doing f-string?
Suppose I have code I want to be able to run in production or verbose mode. In verbose, I want to print debug information that will slow the program down:
import logging
import time
import sys
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
root = logging.getLogger()

def expensive_verbose_info():
    time.sleep(1)
    return "Useful (but expensive) logging information!"

def my_function():
    logging.info("Entering my_function...")
    logging.debug("debug info: %s", expensive_verbose_info())
    logging.info("Exiting my_function...")

my_function()

The program will still hit the time.sleep.
We can make various wrappers around this:
class DeferredCall():
    def __init__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs))

logging.debug("debug info: %s", DeferredCall(expensive_verbose_info))

(This correctly sleeps if logging level is DEBUG and prints correctly if logging is INFO)
Or we can do a manual check and some variety of short-circuit/inline if, but that isn't much better than just having if VERBOSE: scattered everywhere around the code
root.level <= logging.DEBUG and logging.debug("debug info: %s", expensive_verbose_info())

It seems like ideally I'd want something like
logging.debug("debug info: %s", lambda: expensive_verbose_info(), execute_callable=True)

or some way to make a lazy f-string literal? E.G. lf"this will only evaluate when __str__() is called on it"
Does anything like this exist in logging (or in the broader python ecosystem?) Are there reasons to not implement this in my own code?

I googled "Python logging callback" and found these, if they help: How do I call a Python function when something is logged; Python logger with a callback function

@wjandrea I like the thought. It looks like https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Filter.filter you can modify a record in-place, so you could apply a filter that evaluates lambdas if it finds them. There's a lot of places to put that, though. (you could also subclass Logger)

I also found discussion here: https://discuss.python.org/t/safer-logging-methods-for-f-strings-and-new-style-formatting/13802/9
